# Bootstrapping for imbalanced and small sample sized data

Tags: r, logistic, bootstrap, unbalanced-classes

I have a logistic regression model (relogit to be precise) with small sample sizes in the target group (~5%). So far I'm cautiously optimistic with my model and I would like to thoroughly test it. I'm using R and I've so far looked at cross-validation with the caret package. The train-function from caret compares the target values with the output of the model as categorical (i.e. rounded to 0 or 1) value.

Since the respons variable of the model is always < 0.5, it always rounds them down to 0, classifying every point as outside the target group. This is obviously not helpful. As a matter of fact, I am not even interested in getting good predictions on every input point, as there is too much noise. I just need to estimate the *total number* of cases in the target group given a population of test-cases.

So far I have manually created train and testset. On the testset, I have simply summed up the predicted probabilities, which gave me the desired total number.

I did some more research and found out that people call this a bootstrapping approach. So I've tried the following with the boot-Package:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(546)   # for reproducibility
options(scipen=999)
```

generate some data that looks like mine (including a column with the forecasted values from my model):

```
BootData <- data.table(age=sample(15:70,50,replace=TRUE),
                 realval = rbinom(1000,prob = 0.05,size = 1),
                 forecast= 0.1*runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1))

bootfun <- function(DT, i, Resp="realval", RespForecast="forecast"){
  DT1 <- DT[i,]
  mycols <- c(Resp, RespForecast)
  return(DT1[,.(mycols, summe=lapply(.SD, sum),.N), .SDcols = mycols])
}
```

This function would give me this result performed on the entire data:

```
bootfun(BootData)

     mycols     summe   N 
1:  realval       51 1000
2: forecast 50.47873 1000
```

Is it possible to wrap this into a bootstrap? Here is what I've tried:

```
require(boot)
bootStrap <- boot(BootData, bootfun, R=50)
```

Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix